# Vuejs - How to communicate changes between parent and child in scoped slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a component which has two slots. The second slot is repeating based on the number of items in the first slot. I have achieved this using scoped slots, however, when the data is updated on the first slot, the second slot does not automatically update it until an event is triggered, eg: click of a button which calls a method.

Is there a way to make the second slot updates its view when the data is changed on the first slot?

Here is the example that I have:

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89vykm75/1/

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  components: {
   'repeat-for-each-item': {
      data: function() {
          return {
              items: []
          }
      },
     template: `<div>
          <slot name="item" v-for="item in items" :item="item"></slot>
          <button @click="addItem()">Add item</button>
          <slot name="repeat" v-for="item in items" :item="item"></slot>
      </div>
      `,
      methods: {
        addItem() {
          this.items.push({});
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <repeat-for-each-item>
    <template slot="item" scope="props">
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="props.item.name">
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <template slot="repeat" scope="props">
      <div>
        <label>
            <span v-if="props.item.name">{{props.item.name}}:</span>
            <span v-else>No Name:</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </template>
  </repeat-for-each-item>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are falling into a Vue [change detection caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). The issue here is if you add a property to an object that didn't exist before when the object was added to the Vue data, then Vue cannot detect the change. Here is the problem:

```
this.items.push({})
```

You're adding an object with no properties, and then you bind `v-model` to the `name` property of that object, which does not exist. Vue cannot detect the change, and does not update the other items bound to that property.

If you instead did this:

```
this.items.push({name: null})
```

You will find your code works. Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89vykm75/3/).

Comment: This is excellent, thank a lot for this! There is still a lot for me to learn :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by calling a method on keyup.

Basically, I added @keyup event on the slot

```
<input type="text" v-model="props.item.name" @keyup="props.onchange()">
```

And on the component template, pass on the onchange method to the slot

```
<slot name="item" v-for="item in items" :item="item" :onchange="onchange"></slot>
```

And then have the onchange function to force the re-render

```
onchange:() => {
    // hack to trigger changes
    this.$set(this.items, 0, this.items[0]);
}
```

Here is the full working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89vykm75/2/

I wonder if there is a cleaner solution?